# SQL query for getting no duplicated other field

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you help me to build a SQL query?

For example i have this table `table` :

```
FK1 | FK2
 1  |  1
 1  |  2
 1  |  3
 1  |  4
 1  |  1 (duplicated ID)
 2  |  1
 2  |  2
 2  |  3
 2  |  5
```

And i would like to get all `FK1` groups with distinct `FK2` rows count, like that :

```
FK1 | COUNT(FK2)
 1  | 4 // (Distinct ID : 1, 2, 3, 4)
 1  | 1 // (Distinct ID : 1)
 2  | 4 // (Distinct ID : 1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Is it possible in SQL? Maybe with nested queries, i don't know...

Thank you for yours answers (i hope)

Phil

Comment: Why the second row (` 1  | 1 // (Distinct ID : 1)`) in your expected result ? Please explain this.

Comment: What would you want `FK2 = 1` counted twice?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think this might do what you want:

```
select fk1, rn, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@fk2 = fk2, @rn + 1,
                        if(@fk2 := fk2, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @fk2 := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by fk1, fk2
     ) t
group by fk1, rn;
```

At least, this returns the result set that you have specified.